# In JSF is there a way to add a passThroughAttribute to a component based on a condition or parameter?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have an "inputSecret" component and I need to enable both HTML native non null validation, as well as JSF validation. Or to switch both of them off based on a parameter.

As a start, I have the `xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html` and `xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core` namespaces imported

This code

```
<h:inputSecret required="#{passwordRequired}" >
</h:inputSecret>
```

will enable JSF validation if the passwordRequired parameter is 'true'. And I thought the "required" attrib would also translate into the final HTML to enable native HTML validation, but it does not. So then I used the passThroughAttribute to have the "required" attribute down into the HTML rendered component.

```
<h:inputSecret required="#{passwordRequired}" >
    <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="#{passwordRequired}" />
</h:inputSecret>
```

One problem is that the value of the passThroughAttribute does not really matter, I can set it to "required", "true", "false" or even empty string, the HTML native validation will just occur if I type in the passThroughAttribute tag as described above (again, regardless of value).

This would be fine for the use case I initially had, but there is also a situation in which the use case does not require the user to change the password, so I would like to be able to conditionally add that "required" attrib as a "passThroughAttribute" tag in the JSF code.

Something ala

```
<h:inputSecret required="#{passwordRequired}" >
    <if:condition value="#{passwordRequired}">
        <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true" />
    </if>
</h:inputSecret>
```

For an UI component I would use the "render" attribute, but this is not the case. I simply want to be able to switch the inclusion of the "passthroughAttribute" on or off based on my parameter. I know it sounds like JSTL and "c:if" but that doesn't always work so I need something else.

Does anyone know of a method for me to accomplish what I need without some horrible hacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSTL `<c:if>`:

```
<!-- xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" -->

<h:inputSecret required="#{passwordRequired}" >
    <c:if test="#{passwordRequired}">
        <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true" />
    </c:if>
</h:inputSecret>
```

As alternative, you could duplicate the code with a `rendered` condition:

```
<h:inputSecret required="#{passwordRequired}" rendered="#{passwordRequired}">
    <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="#{passwordRequired}" />
</h:inputSecret>
<h:inputSecret required="#{passwordRequired}" rendered="#{!passwordRequired}"/>
```

Comment: As to your JSTL unawareness (based on original answer), carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense

Comment: @BalusC In my original answer, I wrote that I can't try it at the moment, so I can't tell for sure will it work or not. Thanks for the JSTL info, it was helpful.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for yout input, I was trying to avoid JSTL exactly because I had skimmed through some posts that said JSF and JSTL don't mix well, but your post made more sense of that. The <c:if> solution seems to work in this case however so I will consider the question solved.